# SimpleModal: window resize causes scrollbar and redraw of modal content

Tags: javascript, callback, resize, simplemodal

I have a modal that looks like I want it to when it first loads.  To set the size and position in the onShow callback I'm using:

```
$j('.discount-msg').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();

    modalWindow = $j('#crosssell-modal').modal({
        containerId: "cross-sell-container",
        autoResize: true,
        //maxWidth: 698,
        onShow: function (dialog) {
            dialog.container.css({"height":"auto","width":"auto"})
            this.setPosition();

            $j("#closeCrossSellModal", dialog.data).click(function () {
                $j.modal.close();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When a user resizes the browser window though the modal resizes the content width and it breaks over to a new line and creates a scrollbar.

Is there a onResize callback or a way to trigger an event from outside of the modal function?

Comment: is the scrollbar on x or y axis? then i think this is a css problem and it can be easly fixed via css..

Comment: It's on right side.  And I think you are correct about the fix being in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured this out.

In the CSS, if I put a `width: auto`, and `height: auto !important` this works as I'm expecting it to.  I really don't like using the `!important`, but that's what it's for I guess.

Comment: if you can edit the plugin css is better althought you need to use that if you want to override the plugin css rules :P